# I am having some sort of jquery conflict or issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

If you take a look at this page `http://50.87.6.244/~storeupp/index.php/basketball/lebron-james-dwyane-wade-dual-signed-basketball.html` you will notice that everything works great except for the little red arrow that is in the footer. This arrow is suppose to expand an additional footer area. This worked fine until I added the infortis cloudzoon scripts which are:

```
http://50.87.6.244/~storeupp/js/infortis/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
http://50.87.6.244/~storeupp/js/infortis/jquery/jquery-noconflict.js
http://50.87.6.244/~storeupp/js/infortis/jquery/plugins/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js
```

The cloudzoon is what makes the product image larger when hovered over. I also see in the source files that there is a second cloudzoom script and a different version of jquery being called first. I am not sure what the exact issue is here and how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: page throws errors on load... use browser console to inspect details. Also numerous duplication of scripts loading... I counted 3 versions of jQuery at least when only one is needed and additional versions can wipe out plugins already loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You references jQuery library twice: the first occurence references the 1.6.2 version : `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://50.87.6.244/~storeupp/js/etheme/dresscode/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>` and then, after a few js files dependent on jQuery you add adding another one `script` element for 1.7.1 version:  `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://50.87.6.244/~storeupp/js/infortis/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>`
Try to replace the 1.6.2 script element with 1.7.1